# Overloading bitwise & c++ as non-member function

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

Trying to overload bitwise & in c++ as a non-member function

myClass.h

```
class myClass
{
     public:
     myClass(double);
     void setSomeValue(double);
     double getSomeValue() const{
        return someValue;
     }
     /*...more methods...*/


      private:
      double someValue;
};
```

myClass.cpp

```
myClass::myClass(double someValue){
    setSomeValue(someValue);
}
myClass::setSomeValue(double someValue){
    this->someValue = someValue;
}
double operator&(myClass &lhs, myClass &rhs){
    return lhs.getSomeValue() * rhs.getSomeValue();

}
```

I was told I should be able to have a non member function that's not declared as a friend by accessing a classes private members through the classes getters. However when I try:

```
int main(){
    myClass A(0.1);
    myClass B(0.1);

    double test = A & B;
 }
```

I just get an error message that says no operator "&"matches these operands. How can I make this work/what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What you did wrong is that you did not include [mcve] in your question, because the shown code (after fixing a few unrelated typos) compiles without any errors with gcc 5.3. stackoverflow.com fail. But looking for _real_ problems, the likely problem is that the parameters to the overload must be constant references, not mutable references.

Comment: [Cannot reproduce](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7ec3446d5bc8b5ba)

Comment: What do you think `myClass A(double);` should mean? Just write `myClass A;`.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik There is no requirement that they be constant references.

Comment: They could be passed by value, or be rvalue references, sure. But since temporaries do not bind the mutable reference, of course, this operator cannot be used with rvalues.

Comment: `double operator&(myClass &lhs, myClass &rhs)` must have a declaration in `myClass.h` (assuming `int main()` is not in `myClass.cpp`)

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Fixed the code to be more complete, didn't mean to confuse anyone, just didn't want anyone to have to read more than what's necessary

Comment: @LBaelish posting less than necessary is worse than posting more than necessary

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the "corrected" code either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you do not include a declaration of your & operator in your main program. Try to place

```
double operator&(myClass &lhs, myClass &rhs);
```

in your myClass.h file.

Comment: No, it's not. The question is clearly referencing non-member operator overloading. Operator overloads do not have to be class members. And, as the other answer shows, the given code compiles perfectly, without any errors. Wrong answer.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I think this is the right answer.  The other answer did not use the same file structure as OP.  This answer is not suggesting a class member so IDK what you are talking about.

Comment: This was correct. I was under the impression that it was only friend functions that got declared in the header file and non-member functions like this do not. But that was wrong. Thank you.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik - funny thing: the person who asked the question says it's the right answer. And it **doesn't** say anything about `operator&` having to be a class member. Don't get hung up on proving that the question is poorly worded; this is the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a fixed version of your code example (I couldn't reproduce the *`no operator "&"matches these operands`* error message at any stage though):

`myClass.h`

```
class myClass
{
     public:
     myClass() : someValue() {}
     double getSomeValue() const{
        return someValue;
     }
     //...more methods...//


      private:
      double someValue;
};

// ***********************************************************************************
// * You need to make that global operator override visible through the header file: *
// ***********************************************************************************
inline double operator&(myClass &lhs, myClass &rhs){
    return lhs.getSomeValue() * rhs.getSomeValue();

}
```

`main.cpp`

```
#include <iostream>
#include "myClass.h"

int main(){
    myClass A;
    myClass B;

    double test = A & B;
    std::cout << test << std::endl;

 }
```

[<kbd>Live Demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f6f4b0f149916525)

Comment: This is also the correct answer, but I gave the check to the person below since they answered first.